# "createlang" command is not found in archlinux

Tags: postgresql, archlinux

I use postgreSQL in archlinux, whene I try to use "createlang" command, I can not find it.
I searched for it via the command "find", and no resut.
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using PostgreSQL v10 or later.

The `createlang` executable has been removed in v10 (it has been deprecated since 9.1).

Use the SQL statement `CREATE EXTENSION` instead.